# Off-screen multiple render targets using Frame Buffer Object (FBO) or?

Tags: opengl, rendering, framebuffer, edge-detection, fbo

**Situation:** Generating N samples of a shape and corresponding edges (using Sobel filter or my own) with different transformations and rotations, while viewport (size=600*600) and camera remain constants. i.e. there will be N samples + N corresponding edges.

**I am thinking to do like this,**

Use One FBO with 2 renderbuffers [i.e. size of each buffer will be= (N *600) * 600]- 1st for N shapes and 2nd for edges of the corresponding shapes

**Questions:**

1. Which is the best way to achieve above things?
2. Though viewport size is 600*600pixels but shape will only occupy around 50*50pixels. So is there any efficient way to apply edge detection on bounding box/AABB region only on 2nd buffer? Also only reading 2N bounding box (N sample + N corresponding edges) in efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 : I'm not sure what you call "best way". Use Multiple Render Targets : you create two 600*N textures, bind them both to the FBO with glDrawArrays, and in your fragment shader, so something like that :

```
layout(location = 0) out vec3 color;
layout(location = 1) out vec3 edges;
```

When writing to "color" and "edges", you'll effectively write in your textures.

2 : You shouldn't do this. Compute your bounding boxes on the CPU, and project them (i.e. multiply each corner by your ModelViewProjection matrix) to get the bounding boxes in 2D

By the way : Compute your bounding boxes first, so that you won't need 600*600 textures but 50*50...

EDIT : You usually restrict the drawn zone with glViewPort. But ther is only one viewport, and you need several. You can try the [Viewport array extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/viewport_array.txt) and live on the bleeding edge, or pass the AABB in a texture, or don't worry about that until performance matters...

Oh, and you can't use Sobel just like that... Sobel requires that you can read all texels around, which is not the case since you're currently rendering said texels. Either make a two-pass algorithm without MRTs (first color, then edges) or don't use Sobel and guess you edges in the shader ( I don't really see how )

Comment: @Calvin- Thanks. 2- it is 'around' 50*50 i.e. will vary because sometime it might be larger or smaller as well due to z-transformation effect of perspective projection. so could not do that. Only trick we could do here is reading I think.

Comment: @Calvin- please consider that I never used shader. Cannt I use: 

layout(location = 0) out vec3 color; 

edge = iif ( (color[i, j-1] != color[i,j+1] || (color[i-1, j] != color[i+1,j] ) 1:0;  

layout(location = 1) out vec3 edges;

Comment: @Calvin- i.e. if I could do as said in above comment (asseccing neighbour)so then forgot the question (2) for now, I could use ONE FBO, TWO texture bufferS with FRAGMENT SHADER to achive my first goal? right?

Comment: @Rudi you can't access neighbours in a texture IF you are rendering (via FBO) to the same texture (which seems logical). So : Render you scene in one FBO with 1 color texture & 1 depth buffer, and then, render the generated texture (in a simple quad) in *another* FBO, with a Sobel fragment shader. more info : http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

Comment: @Calvin, thanks! I got it! now one last question I guess :D. Which is better using 2 FBOs OR 1 FBO and 2 textures: first draw to one texture then use this as texture to draw to 2nd texture? I mean changing draw target with glWritePixels? Because I read in many places that changing FBO is still costly than changing texture/render buffers?

Comment: Excellent question. No idea. Could you try both and post numbers? Intuitively, I'd say that in both case, you'll have to change the shader and to rebind the FBO, so there won't be much difference, but this is pure speculation.

Comment: Hey Calvin... sorry mate, dont call me lazy! using single FBO full-fill my purpose at the movement. Let's trust official document- changing render traget is faster than changing FBO! Thank you Calvin!!!

Answer (score 1):

Like Calvin said, you have to first render your object into the the first framebuffer and then bind this as texture (use texture attachment rather than a renderbuffer) for the second pass to find the edges, as the edge detection usually needs access to a pixel's surrounding pixels.

Regarding your second question, you could probably use the stencil buffer. Just draw your shapes in the first pass and let them write a reference value into the stencil buffer. Then do the edge detection (usually by rendering a screen sized quad with the corrseponding fragment shader) and configure the stencil test to only pass where the stencil buffer contains the reference value. This way (assuming early-z hardware, which is quite common now) the fragment shader will only be executed on the pixels the shape has actually been drawn onto.

Comment: @Christian- Is not using One FBO with 2 texture buffers and applying fragment shader we could achive first task best way? as suggested by Calvin instead of changing FBOs? i.e. one textrue will have shape color output and another will have edge using fragment shader?

Comment: @Rudi Yes, but like Calvin said, you cannot draw the shapes and compute the edges in the same pass, as the edge detector needs access to neighbouring pixels.

Comment: Yep. Hence my new comment. It makes sense, btw : you can't access your neighbour, you don't even know if it's already been computed or not !